# guide for developing native iOS app by Kivy with PyObjus

Tags: ios, macos, kivy

I'm a beginner. I'm interesting with Kivy. But I want to develop native iOS app via PyObjus. And I installed PyObjus by command:

```
$python setup.py install
```

And , I obtained to declare module pyobjus in terminal python.Then, I successfully built Project'exmaple-ball by command:

```
./toolchain.py create Ball ball-example
```

And run Xcode. But, when I run project'example-ball with simulator and iPhone 3gs , Xcode shown logging:

```
no module named pyobjus
```

You can visit: https://pyobjus.readthedocs.org. I'm a newbee , so I need detail guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should build it for compilation to iOS. Try the following command:

```
./toolchain.py build pyobjus
```